# Failed to start AFC service when access app container using libimobiledevice

Tags: ios, bash, libimobiledevice

I'm trying to access app container with libimobiledevice and copy some logs in iPhone 5 iOS 10.3:

```
# Mount the app container
ifuse Downloads/device_mounts/$DeviceId -u $DeviceId --container $BundleId
```

But I have the following error:

Failed to start AFC service 'com.apple.mobile.house_arrest' on the device.

I would appreciate any help, thanks in advance!